# Any risk in using numeric item numbers in Shopware?

Tags: shopware

The [German community documentation about item numbers](http://community.shopware.com/_detail_642.html) says that the item number **may not** consist only of numerals, while the [English documentation](http://en.community.shopware.com/_detail_1506.html) says "shouldn't":

> As a general rule you shouldn't use spaces or only numeric item numbers.

Is there any risk in using numeric item numbers? Why does the documentation forbid / advice against it?

I tried adding an item with an item number of `999999` and it *seems* to work fine. I’d like to use numeric item numbers because they are already used in that form in a printed catalog.

Comment: (There’s a [German thread in the Shopware community forum](http://forum.shopware.com/allgemein-f25/artikelnummer-alphanumerisches-pflichtzeichen-mythos-t26149.html) about the same question, but it’s not answered.)

Comment: Did you give it a try? What was you result?

Comment: @Roman: I’m using numeric only item numbers and didn’t notice any problems … yet (who knows, maybe a feature I might need in the future will break or something).